# Cannot login to Area 51

Tags: bug, status-norepro, area-51, login, stack-exchange-openid

When I attempt to login to Area 51, with the Stack Exchange OpenID, it gives me the following error:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> The openid.return_to parameter ([http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate/[...]](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate/%5B...%5D)) does not match the actual URL ([https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate/[...]](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate/%5B...%5D)) the request was made with.

[I removed parts of the links to keep my private information private.]

This has happened to me every time I have tried to login to Area 51 in the last few weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can now login to my account on Area 51 without any issues.

It seems that this bug is fixed.